# What is the smallest $m>0$ for the Frobenius automorhism of a Galois Field to be the identity?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Surprisingly scarce information on this particular problem.

> $\phi$ is the Frobenius automorphism of $GF(p^n)$ for some prime $p$. Find the smallest $m>0$ such that $\phi^m$ is the identity element.

Well, I guess I'm right to say that $\phi(x)=x^p$ for each $x \in GF(p^n)$ yes? So $\phi^m(x)=(x^p)^m=x^{mp}$ and we want this to be the identity, which is...$1$? Then $x^{mp}-1=0$. But I get stuck here. I feel that $m=n$ is the answer but not very sure how to find the correct answer properly.

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: The "identity element" here is not $1$ but $Id$, so you want $\phi^m(x)=x$ and not $\phi^m(x)=1$ (which is impossible, look at $x=0$). Also, $\phi^m(x)=x^{p^m}$ and not $x^{mp}$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the support; I'm surprised i'm rusty just now, isn't $\phi^m(x)=\phi (x) \phi (x)... \phi (x) = (x^p)(x^p)...(x^p) = x^{mp}$? What am I doing wrong here?(sorry it's very elementary)

Comment: Non, here $\phi^m$ means $\phi\circ \phi\circ \cdots \circ \phi$ and not pointwise multiplication. It's the multiplication in the group of automorphisms of your field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that the Frobenius automorphism is defined by $\phi(x)=x^p$. But here $\phi^m$ stands for the $m$-th iteration of $\phi$, which means
$$\phi^m(x)=\phi(\phi(\dots \phi(x)))=x^{p^m}.$$

Now what you want is $\phi^m=Id$, so that $\phi^m(x)=x$ for all $x$. So you're looking for $m>0$ such that
$$x^{p^m}=x$$for all $x\in GF(p^n)$. In particular, you want the polynomial $X^{p^m}-X$ to have $p^n$ roots, so certainly $m\geq n$. Moreover, the equality
$$x^{p^n}=x$$
does hold for all $x\in GF(p^n)$, so $m=n$ is your solution.

Comment: Thanks! one tiny question; is there a way I can expand to say $x^{p^{n}}=x$ holds for all $x$? Can I just simply say because $GF(p^n)$ has order $p^n$ and will that suffice?

Comment: @JohnTrail The multiplicative group of $GF(p^n)$ has order $p^n-1$ (because only $0$ has no inverse), so $x^{p^n-1}=1$ for all $x\neq 0$. This implies $x^{p^n}=x$, which is also true for $x=0$.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot!